# xmlrc import server doesn't work

Tags: python

```
import sys    
from xmlrpc import Server
server = Server("https://rnw.ce.aus.net/pdf/")
```

I get the below error,

```
File "conf_export.py", line 2, in <module>
    from xmlrpc import Server
ImportError: cannot import name 'Server
```

Am using version 3.5.3. Please help as am new to python.

'

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.server.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this is an example

```
 from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer

 def is_even(n):
  return n%2 == 0

  server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000))
  print("Listening on port 8000...")
  server.register_function(is_even, "is_even")
  server.serve_forever()
```